# High CPU utilisation with Spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, multithreading

I am running a *Spring boot application* that creates over **200 threads** of which invoke **API** calls to another REST service.
The problem is as soon as I initiate the method to start the process, the CPU Utilisation % goes above **350%**. I have used a `ThreadPoolExecutor, ThreadPoolTaskExecutor AsyncTaskExecutor` to manage the API calls with `AsyncRestTemplate`, but this has made no difference.

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String main(){
    //executor.submit(coins_);
    AsyncTaskExecutor threadpoolExtractor = appCtx.getBean(AsyncTaskExecutor.class);
    asyncRestTemplate = new AsyncRestTemplate((AsyncListenableTaskExecutor) threadpoolExtractor);
}
```

`Get` method from another class.

```
public String GET(String desiredUrl, AsyncRestTemplate asyncRestTemplate)  { 
    String response;
    try {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        response = asyncRestTemplate.exchange(desiredUrl, HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<>("result", headers), String.class).get().getBody();

        return response;
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(HTTP_Methods.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: and.. what is your problem? using async with immediate get you have effectively creating synchronous calls (search for correct usage). you are starting 200 threads and wondering about high cpu usage? how does it work with 5 threads? or 5 with correct async usage? did you try to profile to see what is eating cpu?

Comment: i obviously researched before hand how many threads 4gb RAM could handle and it was way above 200 so i thought it would be alright. even with 5 it still rises to the same figure. ill research into using async in the correct way. i saw what was eating the CPU. it was all the dynamic threads that were created from the application that were making constant API calls. @gusto2

Comment: what I'd like you to understand is that using 200 threads won't make your app much faster unless you have like 50 cores. (creating and switching threads is expensive operation) . 350% CPU means that 4 cores are used almost to their extend. Still it is unclear what is your problem and what do you want to achieve ?  (high CPU usage is good with well written performance application as it means your app is doing something and not waiting, that's why I suggested you'd profile your app to see if it's not processing something useless)